# The classification of order types

Tags: order-theory, ordinals

In response to a previous question which I asked concerning the order type of the Rationals, a reference was made (by MDJ) to a theorem of Cantor stating that any two countable, dense, linearly ordered sets without endpoints are isomorphic as linear orderings.

My question is : If we remove the endpoints condition, say by looking at the intersection of Q and [0,1], then is this order type also unique (upto isomorphism) amongst such linear, dense, countable orderings.

More generally, have all of the (linear) order types which do not correspond to an ordinal number been classified?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Up to isomorphism there are exactly four countable dense linear orders:

- Those without endpoints, like $\Bbb Q$ or $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)$.
- Those with a left endpoint but no right endpoint, like $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)$.
- Those with a right endpoint but no left endpoint, like $\Bbb Q\cap(0,1]$.
- Those with both endpoints, like $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$.

However, there are many other countable order types that are not represented by ordinals. For starters, there are the order types $\alpha^*$ for countable ordinals $\alpha$, obtained by reversing the ordering of $\alpha$: these are the types of the countable reverse well-orderings. There is the type $\omega^*+\omega$, which is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ in its natural order. There are types like $\omega^*+\eta+\omega$, where $\eta$ is the order type of the rationals. And you can combine the types $\alpha$ and $\alpha^*$ for $\alpha<\omega_1$ with $\eta$ to get a huge variety. (The last three types above can be formed in this way: $\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)$ has the type $1+\eta$, and the other two have types $\eta+1$ and $1+\eta+1$, respectively.)

And when you get to uncountable order types, life gets much more complicated. For example, there is not just one dense linear order of cardinality $\omega_1$ without endpoints.

Comment: Or, to put in a concise way: every dense countable order is fully determined by its end points.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott That was quick and easy.  My intuition helped me to identify those four, but it was not clear if they were the only possibilities.  Cheers dear.

Comment: @Nick: You can use minor modifications of the back-and-forth argument that establishes the uniqueness of the countable dense linear order w/o endpoints to show the uniqueness of each of these.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes. That is a very revealing way to characterize it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks for editing your answer with details of reverse orderings.  I must admit, in all of my naive scribblings, I have somehow missed considering the order type of the integers.  And yes, I see how this is obtained by adding reverse-omega to omega.  The other, more exotic order types you give are also very interesting.  I assume that, by definition, all order types can be written as ordinal-arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry, I made a terrible blunder in my previous comment and it is too late to edit.  Obviously, these are not ordinal-arithmetic expressions, since not all of the terms are ordinals.  I guess, order-type-arithmetic expressions would be more appropriate.

Comment: @Nick: Even countable order types can get more complicated than I indicated. For instance, there is the type $\omega\cdot\eta$, which is the type of the lexicographic order on $\Bbb Q\times\omega$, a densely ordered countable sum of well-orders of type $\omega$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thanks again.  I was thinking about orders such as omega times eta during last night's scribblings.  I am also intrigued by your comment that the uniqueness of eta (upto isomorphism) amongst countable, dense,... orderings is not carried forward to uncountable orderings.  Obviously the jump from countable to uncountable leaves intuition severely shaken. Here's the good news : I order a text on Set Theory last night. Assuming I don't have a question about page numbers, that should keep me occupied for a while.